# Juggling multiple lsp-mode servers for the same file extension

Tags: lsp-mode

My emacs is set up with lsp-mode that works well for TypeScript & JSX using `ts-ls`. However, now that I'm exploring deno, lsp-mode incorrectly sets up my deno projects with `ts-ls`, and I can't figure out how to tell lsp-mode to initialize the workspace with the [deno LSP](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-deno/) instead.

My current emacs config utilizes web-mode + lsp-mode:

```
(use-package web-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode (("\\.ts\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.js\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.tsx\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.jsx\\'" . web-mode))
  :config
  (setq web-mode-content-types-alist
    '(("jsx" . "\\.js[x]?\\'"))))

(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook (web-mode . lsp)
  :commands lsp)
```

I've used a `.dir-locals.el` solution before for something that is somewhat similar, by setting the Yarn 2+ TypeScript server to a different path: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#emacs. However, this case is slightly different. I don't need a different server for `ts-ls`, I need to initialize the workspace with deno LSP.

What's the best way to set lsp-mode's language server based on a directory? I'd like `ts-ls` to be the default, and deno LSP only in specific cases, probably by project directory (since the file extension is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was still solvable with `.dir-locals.el`. Here's what I needed to get it to work:

```
((nil . ((lsp-enabled-clients . '(deno-ls)))))
```